# Helpshift FATAL EXCEPTION [android]

Tags: android, helpshift

My project Integrated Helpshift SDK.
Before updated current version sdk v3.9.0, my app running ok.
But this time I have falta exception. This is logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5111
    Process: my.packge.app, PID: 14498
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.helpshift.util.HSTimeUtil
            at com.helpshift.HSApiClient.addAuth(HSApiClient.java:179)
            at com.helpshift.HSApiClient.access$100(HSApiClient.java:59)
            at com.helpshift.HSApiClient$1.run(HSApiClient.java:229)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Helpshift is Libs compiled. so I can't change it.

This's my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    jumboMode = true
}
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.package.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled=true

}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
productFlavors {
}

}
repositories {
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile project(':HelpShift')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

Please help me fix this error. Thanks and best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Paranjay here from Helpshift.

As it is mentioned you can grab the latest version through gradle by adding these dependencies :

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
compile 'com.helpshift:android-aar:3.9.0'
}
```

And then you can set the SDK version requirement as mentioned here :
https://developers.helpshift.com/android/getting-started/#version-requirements

You can report any problem or issues you are facing on our support email : support@helpshift.com.

This will ensure you a quick reply .

Thanks.

Comment: Hello friend I am Ganpat Kaliya, and I am using HelpShift FAQs. Can I remove Conversation or Chat Icon from HelpShift FAQs home screen ? Conversation or Chat icon only display on Question-Answer screen. Is it posible ? if yes, Then how ? please reply. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than building the HelpShift sdk as a project locally you can grab the latest version from the repository. Note that the Android v4 support library is also required:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.helpshift:android-aar:3.9.0'
}
```

An example of this is in the HelpShift sample gradle build file on GitHub:

https://github.com/helpshift/helpshift-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/HelpshiftDemoGradle/app/build.gradle

Also take a look at the [getting started](https://developers.helpshift.com/android/getting-started/) guide which also lists how to include their sdk in gradle based builds.

Comment: Thank @BrentM. I need change some text in Helpshift, so I had add project lib in my project. In dependencies, have compile project(':HelpShift'), this is helpshiftandroidsdk. My app running ok before I'd upgrade to current versionv 3.9.0. And i've this exception :(

Comment: Ok, Not sure if this will help, but HelpShift mention they require a targetSdkVersion of 21 (yours is 19) https://developers.helpshift.com/android/getting-started/#version-requirements

Comment: I'd change to targetSdkVersion to 22, but I'd revert to old version and it working for me. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: And clean project before start run:(